# Connection pool to DB with JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I'm trying to build a JAX-WS that does a call to a database. In all the tutorials I found the WS has a static variable that holds the connection

```
    private static Connection connection;
```

This connection is then used for all the operations done in the database.

Now my question really is: Does that make sense - especially with high(er) traffic? Isn't it better to create a pool of connections and randomly pick one and use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorials probably are doing it the quick and dirty way. Always use a Managed Connection pool, else you are bound to run into issues, and don't need higher traffic for that.